# Cannot login after install windows on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, bootloader, gpu

I'm running ubuntu 16.04 and I installed the new nvidia card gtx1080 on ubuntu, everything was working fine.

Then I installed windows, so as expected the grub for ubuntu just disappeared (i.e. no choosing operating system after boot), I used boot-repair and got the grub back.

But now although I can boot into ubuntu, I got stuck on the login session(infinite loop) and the display was out of portion(display got larger, not the nice sharp display a gpu gives), any ideas why? I searched for solution online, (and even tried to install windows first then ubuntu, but it was even worse, ubuntu couldn't display properly, either just black screen or also stuck in infinite login loop after I install gtx10800 driver on ubuntu) I run out of methods (I'm new to ubuntu and installing gpu cards)

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say exactly wath is the problem.

I think the best is, to start in recovery mode (Grub - Ubuntu recovery), and deinstall the gtx driver from Ubuntu.

In recovery mode you can access ubuntu shell.

I hope this will help you. Its very difficult to make a remote diagnosis.

Comment: What are the steps in recovery mode t deinstall the gtx driver?